# Teamviewer Wake on LAN - Windows

Tags: networking, windows-10, sleep, teamviewer, wake-on-lan

I’ve tried configure my windows PC to enable with Wake up on LAN via Team Viewer.
Here are my steps :

- enable it on the bio (ASUS X99 Motherboard)
- enable the magic packet sent on the network

[image]

I tried follow this link
https://www.asus.com/us/support/FAQ/114359/

I don’t see any Realtek PCIe … Did I miss install any of the driver ?

In my remote PC, under WOL settings, I’ve added my host PC TeamViewer ID already.

[image]

I’ve tried put my remote PC to sleep and, try to wake it up via my host PC.

[image]

My computer never wake up. I feel like no action is really trigger.

**What steps do I miss ?**

Any hint on this will be much appreciated !

Comment: Are you sure your Firewall doesn't block teamviewer or UDP port "9" !! Also check Windows TCPIP check this documentations http://windows7-issues.blogspot.com.tr/2011/03/wake-on-lan-wol-for-windows-7-made-easy.html

Comment: Thanks the link help a lot. It works now. OMG. This is amazing. I can't believe I did that. :)

Comment: Sometimes you should google more deeply :P